# QuerySelectorAll not working with onclick event

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

### Scenario

I've got some text inputs and I want them to have a width of 500px when they're clicked.

### My code

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
 inputs[i].onclick = function(){
  inputs[i].style.width = "500px";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sometext">
```

### What's not working

On chrome console, I'm getting "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" on the following line: `inputs[i].style.width = "500px";` when I click on the input.

### My question

How can I fix my code?

Comment: See the linked question for ways of handling this oft-encountered issue.

Comment: That's because wheb user click on the input, the `i` var is not defined.

Comment: @Pointy: Technically it's a duplicate but in that question, a new scope is actually needed to solve it. That's not the case here.

Comment: @Stubborn: simply change this: `inputs[i].style.width = "500px";` to this `this.style.width = "500px";`

Comment: @squint Thanks, that works!

Comment: @squint why isn't a new scope necessary (other than something like the availability of `let`)? *edit* oh OK, sure. Maybe that should be included in that centralized repository of answers, as this is a pretty common case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

The reason you're seeing this error is because the `for` loop has already ended and `i` is outside of the bounds of the `inputs` NodeList when the `click` event is fired. In other words, since the last element's index in the array is one less than the length, `inputs[i]` is undefined since `i` is equal to the length of the NodeList when the `click` event listener is fired.

To work around this, you could change `inputs[i]` to `this` in order to access the clicked element. In doing so, you avoid having to use `i` (which is what was causing the problem):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.width = "500px";
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an IIFE in order to pass the value of `i` on each iteration:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      inputs[i].style.width = "500px";
    });
  })(i);
}
```

You could also use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass the value of `i`:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(i) {
    inputs[i].style.width = "500px";
  }.bind(this, i));
}
```