# How to get text from h3 with native js?

Tags: javascript

I have some h3 elements with the same class. I need to get text from h3 when i click on one of the elements.

```
document.querySelector(`.block__item__name`).onclick = function() {
  let value = this.textContent;
  console.log(value);
};
```

This code works with first h3 only. How can i fix it?

Comment: `querySelector` will only match the first element found. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482587/queryselectorall-not-working-with-onclick-event for a way to use `querySelectorAll` instead

Comment: oh ok. So how to solve my problem?

Comment: thx. I tried to use it but it didn't work. I think i did mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const content = document.getElementsByClassName("titel");

for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  content[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let value = this.textContent;
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

You can try it out here: https://jsitor.com/EKnmSAr5J

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) gives you the first result for your query. If you want all results, use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.block__item__name`)forEach(item => {
  item.onclick = function() {
   let value = this.textContent;
   console.log(value);
  };
});
```